# Flutter view open below current one in map_view

Tags: google-maps, dart, flutter

I am using [this](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/map_view) Flutter map plugin. I have some markers on the map, and when I tap them another page should appear on top of the map, but instead I can only see it when I close the map.

I put the following code inside another method, in order to call it more conveniently from a Navigation Drawer:

```
 mapView.show(new MapOptions(...))
```

when a marker is tapped i call this method:

```
showPage(
    info = dbCall();

    Navigator.push(
      context,
      new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new PageDemo(info, id)));
)
```

The things that puzzles me is that the context in MaterialPageRoute is the one of the NavigationDrawer, but I really don't know how to find another way to do it.

Comment: unfortunately this is a limitation because map_view is a native plugin on top of the flutter view. (It's a new Activity/ViewController). There is a work in progress about inline maps but currently is only for android : https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/google_maps_flutter

Comment: I see...thanks for your insight. This plugin you showed me is an official one? I see it comes from a Google group

Comment: Yes, it's the official